# Why do i get the X11 connection broke: error when i run anaconda-navigator on Ubuntu 18.04 terminal?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-18.04

[the error that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Yii.png)

I can run `conda list` and it returns the packages that i have installed. But when I run `anaconda-navigator`, I get :

`The X11 connection broke: Maximum allowed requested length exceeded (code 4)
XIO:  fatal IO error 22 (Invalid argument) on X server ":0"
      after 448 requests (448 known processed) with 0 events remaining.`

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10467 please refer this link. It may help you.

Answer (score 2):

If you work with an external monitor disconnect it, again run anaconda-navigator, enter preferences CTRL + P, deactivate the option "enable high DPI scaling", close anaconda and connect the external monitor, this should work